# Neo4j 2.0.1 graphstyle.grass stylesheet issue

Tags: neo4j

I've somehow managed to import a bad/malformed graphstyle.grass file and now nothing gets displayed in the new (http://< server >:7474/browser/)  graph view. In the table view I can see the nodes, so I know the query is hitting (I'm just using 'match n return n limit 25').

So here's where the rub comes.. because the nodes aren't showing up.. I can't click on them to open the properties where I could say 'View Stylesheet' and hit load default or import a fixed stylesheet. I poked around Neo4j files a bit to see if graphstyle.grass was stored within the files but didn't find anything. Any help is greatly appreciated because I ^think^ the nuclear option is reinstalling the server (which isn't a huge deal but trying to avoid that if I can).

Comment: There is also a small fire-extinguisher icon that should reset the grass style.

Comment: @MichaelHunger I probably didn't clarify that properly.. because in my case I couldn't open the properties dialog  "...and hit load default..."  that wasn't an option. Thankfully Stefan knew exactly how to fix my weird circumstance. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're on chrome browser. Press `F12` to open web developer, tab `Resources`, `Local storage` and remove all the stuff from `<server>:7474`.

Other browser should offer a similar way.